# How to export an Elastic Search index?

Tags: elasticsearch, export, kibana

We are attempting to export a list of two fields (ID, text) from an existing Elastic Search index into a text file.

The index contains approximately 2 million rows of data.  We tried using the reporting feature in Kibana, but ran into the 10K row limit.

Searched online for other options, but haven't found anything viable because I don't think we'll be able to install any 3rd party tools.

Comment: I regularly use [es2csv](https://github.com/taraslayshchuk/es2csv/) and [elasticdump](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticdump) to export index data into files

Answer (score 0):

You may use any REST client with pit API to pagenate documents.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/point-in-time-api.html

Another option is using one of ELK stack: Logstash, Elasticsearch input plugin and File output plugin.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-file.html